# Golang : Scan error on column index 1, name "MIDDLE_NAME": converting NULL to string is unsupported

Tags: sql-server, go, sqlx

I have below golang code which is working fine when there is no null value in the table. But in my table some column called "MIDDLE_NAME" has null value and hence I am getting error

> Scan error on column index 1, name "MIDDLE_NAME": converting NULL to string is unsupported

How do I handle null value in `err := rows.Scan(columnPointers...)`

```
package main


import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func printColumns(rows *sql.Rows) {
    col, err := rows.Columns()
    onError(err)
    var sb strings.Builder
    sb.WriteString("|")
    for _, s := range col {
        sb.WriteString(s)
        sb.WriteString("|")
    }
    log.Println(sb.String())
}

func printRows(rows *sql.Rows) {
    cols, _ := rows.Columns()
    for rows.Next() {
        columns := make([]string, len(cols))
        columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
        for i := range columns {
            columnPointers[i] = &columns[i]
        }

        err := rows.Scan(columnPointers...)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        var sb strings.Builder
        sb.WriteString("|")
        for _, s := range columnPointers {
            sb.WriteString(*s.(*string))
            sb.WriteString("|")
        }
        log.Println(sb.String())
    }
}

func onError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error %s", err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need pointer types or custom sql.Scanner types to be able to scan columns with null values.

Comment: @mkopriva Can you please elaborate? i am pretty new to Golang and pointers?

Comment: In Go string values cannot be `nil` so scanning db NULLs into strings is not allowed, hence the error. Pointer values can be `nil` however, therefore you should use, in this specific case, a pointer to a string rather than just string. The alternative is to use Go types that "know" how to handle db NULLs, i.e. [`sql.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.20.2#Scanner) implementations, e.g. [`sql.NullString`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.20.2#NullString). Or, another alternative, is to use `COALESCE` in the SQL query.

Comment: @mkopriva This is exactly what I was looking for as an answer. You should add it outside of a comment to help the next person get to it more easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `IFNULL(field, default_value)` to return default value if field is null